# Cordova-plugin-firebasex Failed to install Error: pod: Command failed with exit code 1 at ChildProcess.whenDone

Tags: macos, cordova-plugins, cordova-ios, cordova-plugin-firebasex

WEB-IMAC:APP d****an$ cordova platform add ios

Using cordova-fetch for cordova-ios@^6.2.0
Adding ios project...
Creating Cordova project for the iOS platform:
Path: ../../../../desktop/App_Dev/xxxxxx_app/APP/platforms/ios
Package: org.xxxxxxxxxxx.app
Name: xxxxxxxxxxxxx App
iOS project created with cordova-ios@6.3.0
Installing "at.modalog.cordova.plugin.cache" for ios
Installing "cordova-plugin-advanced-http" for ios
Plugin dependency "cordova-plugin-file@7.0.0" already fetched, using that version.
Installing "cordova-plugin-file" for ios
Installing "cordova-plugin-browsersync-gen2" for ios
Installing "cordova-plugin-camera" for ios
Installing "cordova-plugin-clipboard" for ios
Installing "cordova-plugin-deeplinks" for ios
Installing "cordova-plugin-dialogs" for ios
Plugin "cordova-plugin-file" already installed on ios. Making it top-level.
Installing "cordova-plugin-firebasex" for ios
Running command: pod install --verbose
Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-firebasex': Error: pod: Command failed with exit code 1 at ChildProcess.whenDone (/Users/dxxxxxn/desktop/App_Dev/xxxxxx_app/APP/node_modules/cordova-common/src/superspawn.js:136:25)
at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1091:16)
at Socket. (node:internal/child_process:449:11)
at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
at Pipe. (node:net:320:12)
pod: Command failed with exit code 1
WEB-IMAC:APP dxxxxan$

I tried
-cordova platform add ios

was expecting a no issue build of ios

Error shown above happened

I have updated cocoapods to 1.12.1 then did a
-pod repo update
I have also tried to install cordova-plugin-firebasex by its self with no luck

Comment: I figured out all of this was because there was a special character in the app's name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a special character in the name of the app. That caused all of this, so just make sure there is not one in your app.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).